# htaccess for nth level category subcategory pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For my custom php/mysql blog project, I am trying to write the htaccess rule for nth level category/subcategory with pagination for displaying the posts under a specific category. Here is what I did so far:

For URL like "http://my-blog.com/category/nature" which displays top 5 recent posts on one page which falling under category "nature", I am using following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To show next 5 post, my URL becomes "http://my-blog.com/category/nature/page/2", but here I'm stuck and don't know what will be the correct rule. I have tried following but didn't work yet:

```
RewriteRule ^category/page/([0-9]+)/?$ category.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also since my categories and subcategories are of nth-level. So what should I need in htaccess to make me able to work with URLs such as

http://my-blog.com/category/nature/mountains/snow

and

http://my-blog.com/category/nature/mountains/snow/page/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)$ category.php?url=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

First we match categories with pagination. If there is no pagination we match the second rule.

Comment: Wow! that worked superbly. Thanks my friend. Full marks to you. You saved my time to deteriorate. Now I see, the order of htaccess rules also does matter.